# In Delphi mobile development how to edit selected text font within memo

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am trying to create a multi device Firemonkey app. I want to have a memo where I can change font for individual text. But I am not seeing any RichEdit component to do this. Or can I achive this using some other component?

For example how can I do something like this?

**Summary**: ***Delphi*** is famous as the ancient sanctuary that grew rich as the seat of the **oracle** that was consulted on important decisions throughout the ancient classical world. Moreover, it was considered as the navel (or centre) of the world by the Greeks as represented by the **Omphalos**.

Comment: [Professional Rich Edit Component For Delphi XE7 Firemonkey On Android, IOS, OSX, And Windows](http://www.fmxexpress.com/professional-rich-edit-component-for-delphi-xe7-firemonkey-on-android-ios-osx-and-windows/).

Comment: @LURD thanks. Will check. Wish Delhi compe by default for such a basic requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Embarcadero does not (yet?) provide a RichEdit component for FireMonkey.  You will have to use a 3rd party component, such as this one:

[Professional Rich Edit Component For Delphi XE7 Firemonkey On Android, IOS, OSX, And Windows](http://www.fmxexpress.com/professional-rich-edit-component-for-delphi-xe7-firemonkey-on-android-ios-osx-and-windows/)

Comment: thanks for reply. I will look into that. As of now I am testing with Delphi 10.1 (latest). Will any of those let you zoom like browser? if not which component will let you do that.